# Swing GUI freezes after clicking JButton for three times

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, rest

I am trying to write a code that calls an API from CoinMarketCap API and below is the code that calls the api:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

  private static String apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
  private static final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setLayout(null);
      frame.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 250);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      JButton viewInfoButton = new JButton("View CryptoCurrency Lists");
      viewInfoButton.setBounds(30, 10, 200, 30);
      frame.add(viewInfoButton);

      viewInfoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              try {
                  testCallingAPI();
              } catch (URISyntaxException uriSyntaxException) {
                  uriSyntaxException.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException ioException) {
                  ioException.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      });
      }

      public static void testCallingAPI() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
          URIBuilder userBuild =
                  new URIBuilder("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info");
          List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<  >();
          parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1"));
          userBuild.addParameters(parameters);
          HttpGet get = new HttpGet(userBuild.build());

          get.setHeader("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY", apiKey);
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
          BufferedReader rd =
                  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(line + "\n");
              System.out.println(line);
          }
      }
}
```

The above code is a very simple code that is to call the rest API of the CoinMarketCap when clicking a JButton. However, whenever I click a button three times, the GUI freezes (stops).
Also, for example, saying that there is another JButton called "second_button" and it calls the api twice when I click the button. This is regarded as calling the API twice and if I click the first button, it is regarded as a third-call, so the GUI stops.

Can someone please help me with how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Run this code from the command line so that any exceptions that *might* be occurring are shown to you. 2. The long-running code in the `testCallingAPI()` method *must* be performed in a background thread, such as a SwingWorker.

Comment: So, in brief there are two problems here: 1) The GUI is freezing, and this is because long-running code is being called on the Swing event thread, freezing this thread, and is solved by use of a background thread. Then there is 2) *why* the third call to the API causes a freeze, and perhaps a crash. That is why you must call this on the command line or use logging to check any and all exception messages.

Comment: If you're saying that the three clicks have to be in close time to each other, then disable the button until the operation is done, then tenable it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is that code above a long-running code which causes GUI freeze?
Also, no error occurs when I run it using command line... how should I detect exceptions?>

Comment: The code that looks to be blocking includes `HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);` and `while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { sb.append(line + "\n"); System.out.println(line); }`

Comment: If no exceptions are showing, then I would log everything going on in the `testCallingAPI()` method.

Comment: when I run it using stackrace, it shows org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':run'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)

Comment: Also, if that lines would be the problem, in what way I should change it?

Comment: You probably have to look further down the stacktrace.